# Async generation of additional styles in paperclip plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a picture class with many styles in it. I want to process only a coupe of them when the user upload the picture and then queue a task to convert the rest.

How can I do this using paperclip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip) gem might be of use to you.

It works with both [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) and [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

**Update:**

Original project no longer maintained, but a fork is. Updated link to the gem can be found [here](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/)